# JSON math on object array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, math

I'm trying to multiply two components together in my object array

```
{
  "rx": {
    "vials": [
      {
        "description": "Rx 1",
        "strength": 100,
        "form": "ML",
        "pkg_size": 10,
        "case_size": 1,
        "total_units": strength * pkg_size,
        "ndc": "12345-1234-12",
        "covered": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But if I do something like

```
$( "#demo" ).html( rx.vials[0].total_units );
```

I get nothing or `NaN`

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: there's no `insulin` key in your object

Comment: Check the path again! This `rx.insulin.vials[0].total_units` will throw an error if called on the object you provided!

Comment: `strength` and `pkg_size` are both undefined

Comment: That was a typo. Even if I correct the path to `$( "#demo" ).html( rx.vials[0].total_units );` I still don't get what I need.

Comment: Where do `trength * pkg_size` come from? If there is a problem it's in them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try something like this :**

You can add `total_units` property into `vials[0]` after doing the calculation.

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "rx": {
    "vials": [
      {
        "description": "Rx 1",
        "strength": 100,
        "form": "ML",
        "pkg_size": 10,
        "case_size": 1,
        "ndc": "12345-1234-12",
        "covered": true
      }
    ]
  }
};

jsonObj.rx.vials[0].total_units = jsonObj.rx.vials[0].strength * jsonObj.rx.vials[0].pkg_size;

console.log(jsonObj.rx.vials[0].total_units);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that. If you want to do some math inside an object you have to use external variables - you can't access object's properties from within itself.

Comment: So something like `$( "#demo" ).html( rx.vials[0].strength * rx.vials[0].pkg_size );` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rx.vials.length; i++) {
  rx.vials[i].total_units = rx.vials[i].strength * rx.vials[i].pkg_size;
}

console.log(rx.vials[0].total_units);
```